# Сортировка текста в тхт файле по алфавиту

Tags: c#

В тхт файле есть строки типа :

```
294|ab
124h|b4 
903|ac 
626|ad 
2364|ag 
913a|it 
390q|a8
```

есть строка по которой надо сортировать, то есть `string digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";`
но как сделать чтобы строки в тхт  сортировались по алфавиту "digits", но после `|` значка. Если меняется порядок чисел значит меняется и то что до `"|"` знака...если эти числа после `|` повторяются, значит они идут подряд..после сортировки должно быть так:

```
294|ab
903|ac 
626|ad 
2364|ag
390q|a8
124h|b4 
913a|it
```

после `|` знака будет строка, длинна все равно какая, надо все что находится после `|` сортировать по алфавиту

Comment: считать файл, для каждой строки сделать сплит по `|` - пусть то что до  `|` будет значением, а то что после - ключ, и поместить в словарь, отсортировать словарь и перезаписать файл?

Comment: откуда такая задача?

Comment: @Anatol "а то что после - ключ" - какой ключ, можно узнать ? :/

Comment: @Tode Мой вариант проверял? Там все это предусмотрено, только вместо чтения и записи в файл, применил richTextBox1 для наглядности. Поменяв на чтение и запись файла, получите то, что хотите.

Comment: @koshe вместо richTextBox1 надо прописать `File.WriteAllLines` ?

Comment: @Tode Я поправил в ответе на чтение-запись файла.

Comment: @koshe нет эффекта который нужен! По алфавиту надо.........

Comment: Я не понял, нужно сортировать по альфавиту или по заданной в digits строке? Если по альфавиту, регистр учитывать или нет?

Comment: @koshe можно учитывать регистры, не помешает)) по алфавиту надо чтобы было после `|`  и все, больше ниче не надо

Comment: Тогда для чего нужен digits?

Comment: @koshe ну типа алфавит....
другими словами... обновил описание

Comment: @Tode в конце ответа добавил вариант без строки digits, только в альфавите цмфри идут раньше букв. Параметр `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` можно менять по усмотрению.

Comment: Тогда старый вариант с digits, просто в сортировку нужно добавить `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` чтоб игнорировать регистр.

Comment: @koshe теперь гут!!)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала создадим класс:

```
class Line
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Fragment { get; set; }
}
```

и функцию:

```
private string getFragment(string s,string digits)
{           
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return string.Empty;

    var t = s.Split('|');
    if (t.Count() == 1)
        return string.Empty;
    s = t[t.Count() - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
    {
        s = s.Replace(digits[i], (char)i);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Функция берет текст после "|" и меняет для сортировки по digits.
После этого по клику на буттон:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string digits = "0123456789";
    var list = new List<Line>();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename");
    foreach (var s in lines)
    {                
        list.Add(new Line { Text = s, Fragment = getFragment(s,digits) });
    }
    lines = list.OrderBy(r => r.Fragment).Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
    File.WriteAllLines("filename", lines);
}
```

Если просто сортироват по альфавиту, можно так:

```
class Line
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Fragment
    {
        get
        {
            if (Text.Contains("|"))
                return Text.Split('|')[1];
            else return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

var list = new List<Line>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename");
foreach (var s in lines)
{                
    list.Add(new Line { Text = s});
}
lines = list.OrderBy(r => r.Fragment, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("filename", lines);
```

Comment: Ой.. А чего так много кода-то?

Comment: А вообще интересно - держи плюсик. Хотя я бы загнал getFragment в конструктор Line.

Comment: @Qwertiy Справедливое замечание, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, подход, описанный koshe - создание класса-модели - является правильным.

Но если данные из файла нигде более не используются и вся задача сводится только к его сортировке, то можно сделать так:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");

var sorted = lines.OrderBy(line => int.Parse(line.Split('|')[1]));

File.WriteAllLines("test2.txt", sorted);
```

Comment: Вот что пишет
Необработанное исключение типа "System.FormatException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Comment: мне без кнопок надо console app. чтобы отсортировал и сделал перезапись того же файла

Comment: @Tode - Этот код работает на том наборе данных, что приведён в вопросе. В этом коде нет кнопок.

Comment: Он мне еррор выдает..

Comment: @Tode - Я могу лишь повторить: этот код работает на том наборе данных, что приведён в вопросе. Покажите _реальные_ данные.

Comment: а щяс сработал, странноваттттто :/

Comment: @Tode - Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Отредактируйте основной вопрос, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/683720/edit) под ним.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну расскажи, как же на `3a` работает `int.Parse`? UPDATE: Оказывается, вопрос изменился...